# UIWebView looks like different text sign in landscape

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios8

We have some text in a UIWebView.  It appears when the app is rotated, that the text looks bigger in landscape.  Is anyone else seeing this, and is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

yes, that will happen if the content doesn't have any viewport setting.

have a read on how to config your page on apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html and/or use css to style the page.